# Python division of small floats in quaternion calculations

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, quaternions, scipy-spatial

Consider the math equation: y = (sin(x/2)/x) which shows up in the calculation of rotations.  In the limit as x->0 this has a value of 1/2.  Implementing this in Python (or any language with similar 64-bit floating point types) seems to work fine for all values except x = 0.0 exactly.

Yet, when this math shows up in books it is often recommended to implement the function with a truncated Taylor's series expansion that does not have divide by zero issues.  Here is an example in SciPy where a seemingly arbitrary threshold of 1e-3 radians was chosen for this logic.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/9d5d4f86bd50e11ee6e593758ab06f9b6f7cf021/scipy/spatial/transform/_rotation.pyx#L1102

The basic implementation `y = np.sin(x/2)/x` appears to work fine for small values of x (obviously except x = 0.0 exactly).  Is there really a precision issue to be concerned about here?  If so, what is a test case that shows it?

Code to check for 0.0 as a special case is cleaner than using the truncated Taylor series with an arbitrary threshold.

Comment: I would check for `x/2!=0.0`, otherwise you get zero for `x` very close to zero.

Comment: A “well behaved” function can be approximated over an interval with a polynomial. Various factors play into the engineering of the polynomial—larger intervals decrease accuracy, higher degrees increase accuracy but also increase compute time, and whether you engineer the polynomial for minimum absolute error, minimum relative error, or other properties…

Comment: … Once you have picked the goals for your polynomial, one way to set the threshold between computing the function as sin(x/2)/x versus a custom polynomial could be where the interval induced by the threshold results in about an equal amount of work for the same accuracy. E.g., measure how much time using sin(x/2)/x takes, figure out what degree of polynomial you can calculate in the same time, test various intervals to find out how big you can make the interval with the accuracy being the same as for using sin(x/2)/x.

Comment: Implementing the above takes some work with using software to generate minimax polynomials (or whatever other polynomial approximation you are using), and that is a bit much to go into in Stack Overflow. There are books and other resources on implementing the elementary functions, which is applicable to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The basic implementation `y = np.sin(x/2)/x` appears to work fine for small values of x (obviously except x = 0.0 exactly). Is there really a precision issue to be concerned about here? If so, what is a test case that shows it?

Yes. You can see this in the following code sample:

```py
>>> angle = 5e-324
>>> np.sin(angle/2)/angle
0.0
```

More generally, here is the function `np.sin(x/2)/x` plotted from -5e-322 to 5e-322. Recall that the [limit of sin(x/2)/x as it approaches 0 is 1/2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+sin%28x%2F2%29%2Fx+at+0), so this graph should be a nearly straight horizontal line at y=0.5, with one missing value in the middle.

[image: sin(x/2)/x near zero]

(The X axis is missing, because matplotlib freaks out when you try to plot extremely small X values.)

The number 5e-324 is an extreme case, because 5e-324 / 2 is not representable as a float, but the numbers after it aren't great either. The computation `np.sin(x/2)/x` is not consistently accurate to three decimal places until around x=2.5e-321.

> Code to check for 0.0 as a special case is cleaner than using the truncated Taylor series with an arbitrary threshold.

I disagree - code that uses floating point math and checks for exact equality with zero is almost always a code smell. Frequently, if the code has a division by zero when the input is exactly zero, then it is numerically unstable at values near zero.

> Here is an example in SciPy where a seemingly arbitrary threshold of 1e-3 radians was chosen for this logic.

I went looking through SciPy's history to find why the threshold is set at 1e-3 specifically. In the [commit which originally added the 1e-3 threshold](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/commit/46dcfcbe599893a0102a1f3a08277e90dad08ac0), there isn't any discussion about why that value was picked, nor is there any discussion of it in the associated PR. I don't know why this specific threshold value was chosen.

Comment: We're not supposed to acknowledge answers like this, but I want to congratulate you for a thorough, well-stated description of a difficult problem that many programmers silently ignore.  Nicely done.